# Function fails to execute in <a> tag but works with LinkButton

Tags: asp.net, linkbutton, static-functions

I have a static class (SS.U) with a function (GP) that returns true or false. My problem is that this function is not triggered when I use it inside the `<a>` tag, but works fine inside an `asp:LinkButton` tag. I need both of them for some reasons. Here are my code lines:

```
1) <asp:LinkButton Visible='<%# SS.U.GP("EditContactImage") %>' runat="server" ID="LB1" Text="EditImage"/>

2) <a visible='<%# SS.U.GP("EditRelations") %>' runat="server" id="R1">EditRelations</a>

3) <a visible='false' runat="server" id="R2">EditRelations</a>
```

Line 1 and 3 are both working while line 2 always returns "visible = true". (Line 3 is included in the example for showing that the `<a>` tag actually has a working property called "visible"). I did set a breakpoint in the GP function noticing that only line 1 is using my function.
What can cause the `<a>` tag not perform the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer:** 
HTML controls do not support data binding.

**Detailed answer here:**
[When to use runat="server" on normal HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11460121/when-to-use-runat-server-on-normal-html)