# How to take the value from an html input control and insert into sql database

Tags: asp.net, sql

I am working with asp.net controls(textboxes), but only for the calendar control I am using jquery code(because it has a good UI) that has html `<input type="text" id="datepicker">`

Now, I want to insert the value of this input field into the database. 
With asp.net controls,it is easily possible using `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MemberId", txtMemberId.Text);` But I am stuck with the html input control, Please help me out. Thank you.

Comment: if you add runat = server you can call the HTML control. I have done this before. Example <img src = "myimage.png name = "mypicture" runat = "server">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to access the control by doing this:

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" runat = "server">
```

Comment: Thank you, but then how should I insert this value into the database? should I use the id and write `insert into table values('"+datepicker.text+"')` where datepicker is the id of the input control?

Comment: I would assume you use datePicker.value. Once you do runat = Server it will show up in intellesense.

Comment: but now I have another problem, when I combine jquery code with twitter bootstrap the calendar does not show up.How should I solve this.Please help

Answer (score 2):

You can use `runat = "server"` for your `HTML` control or you can alternatively use a `hiddenfield` to store the selected data and this hidden field value can be accessed in your code. You'll have to assign the value of `datepicker.text` to the hidden field through javascript.

You can access the hidden field value in code as `hdnDate.Value`

The link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11460121/when-to-use-runat-server-on-normal-html) will help you understand when to use `runat="server"` on normal HTML controls.